# How to edit or replace xml string using php?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, xml-editor

I had to change my question to simple question

For example: my XML file name is:   **ABC.xml**

inside of this xml file is:

```
<li class="thumb"><a class="Alibaba" href="google.com"></a></li>
```

So, here is my question:
How to use PHP to search string inside of ABC.xml and find **Alibaba** name and replace it to **AlibabaColor** name and save it to **ABC.xml**

Please guide me and give me an example for this. Thank you

Comment: show the code where you getting contents of this xml

Comment: simple str_repalce() by the sounds of it

Comment: How to use str_repalce() with PHP ? could you please tell me an example ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using php [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) among many other functions. Here is a couple examples ->

If the XML is in a string already you can do this

PHP:

```
<?php
    $myXmlString = str_replace('Alibaba', 'AlibabaColor', $myXmlString);
?>
```

If you need to get the XML data from another file there are a few ways to to do it depending on if you need to save it, just replace it and display it, or really what you are doing. Some of this comes down to preference.

Just need to display it?

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents(/path/to/file); // or http://path.to/file.xml
    $myXmlString = str_replace('Alibaba', 'AlibabaColor', $xml);
?>
```

Need to change the file itself?

```
<?php
    $xml = file_get_contents(/path/to/file); // or http://path.to/file.xml
    $myXmlString = str_replace('Alibaba', 'AlibabaColor', $xml);
    file_put_contents(/path/to/file, $myXmlString);
?>
```

--

To answer the below comment, here is working code from my server ->

xml:

```
<li>hello</li>
```

php:

```
$file = '/home/username/public_html/xml.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($file);
$text = str_replace('hello','world',$xml);
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

xml.xml after:

```
<li>world</li>
```

Keep in mind to change 'username' to the right one, or use an FQDN if you are more comfortable doing so. Make sure that the file has permission to be written to by a script as well.

Comment: It doesn't work sir. <?php
    $xml = file_get_contents(ABC.xml); 
    $myXmlString = str_replace('Alibaba', 'AlibabaColor', $xml);
    file_put_contents(ABC.xml, $myXmlString);
?>

Comment: See my edit and adjust to your code accordingly. The code in your comment has some big problems which you should just delete and copy my last piece of code. Good Luck and have fun programming!